# Different matches when using prepared statements on CHAR(3) column

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-xe

I had to make a `CHAR(1 CHAR)` column wider and I forgot to change the column type to `VARCHAR2`:

```
DUPLICADO CHAR(3 CHAR)
```

I noticed the error when my PHP app would no longer find exact matches, e.g.:

```
SELECT *
FROM NUMEROS
WHERE DUPLICADO = :foo
```

... with `:foo` being `#4` didn't find the 3-char padded `#4` value. However, I initially hit a red herring while debugging the query in SQL Developer because injecting raw values into the query would find matches!

```
SELECT *
FROM NUMEROS
WHERE DUPLICADO = '#4'
```

Why do I get matches with the second query? Why do prepared statements make a difference?

Comment: What datatype is your PHP bind variable declared as? The literal `'#4'` is implicitly converted to CHAR(3) and therefore padded with a space. `:foo` bind variable I think is not implicitly converted and expects the clientside to do the padding. I do not know if PHP has CHAR versus VARCHAR2 datatype for bind variables? If you can declare your bind variable in PHP to be CHAR(3) somehow, then it might work, but if PHP just has a "String" datatype, that probably by default maps to VARCHAR2.

Comment: @KimBergHansen Sorry, I haven't tested this with PHP (and I already fixed the column type in the app, so to test it I'd have to rollback to an earlier revision). I found the different behaviours right in SQL Developer.

Comment: Aha. So actually the question could be rephrased to "What datatype is a bind variable in SQL Developer?" I use Toad where it is possible to choose datatype of a bind variable. For your question the answer then is, that the literal value the SQL Engine can figure out what the meaning is and it pads the value with the necessary spaces. For bind variables the SQL engine relies on the client to do padding if necessary. Some clients or client languages have ways to specify datatype so the client knows to pad. The specific client "SQL Developer" might not have that (I don't now for sure ;-)

Comment: Follow-up: I later found that my PHP library wouldn't care setting the bind variable type thus everything was being handled as `VARCHAR` because it was using the OCI8 extension default type (`SQLT_CHR`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand a little on my comments, I found a bit in the documentation that explains difference between blankpadded and nonpadded comparison:

http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements002.htm#BABJBDGB

If both values in your comparison (the two sides of the equal sign) have datatype CHAR or NCHAR or are literal strings, then Oracle chooses blankpadded comparison. That means that if the lengths are different, then it pads the short one with blanks until they are the same length.

With the column `DUPLICADO` being a `CHAR(3)`, the value `'#4'` is stored in the column as three characters `'#4 '` (note the blank as third character.) When you do `DUPLICADO = '#4'` the rule states Oracle will use blankpadded comparison and therefore blankpad the literal `'#4'` until it has the same length as the column. So it actually becomes `DUPLICADO = '#4 '`.

But when you do `DUPLICADO = :foo`, it will depend on the datatype of the bind variable. If the datatype is CHAR, it will also perform blankpadded comparison. But if the datatype is VARCHAR2, then Oracle will use non-padded comparison and then it will be up to you to ensure  to do blankpadding where necessary.

Depending on client or client language you may be able to specify the datatype of the bind variable and thereby get blankpadded or nonpadded comparison as needed.

SQL Developer may be a special case that might not allow you to specify datatype - it just possibly might default to bind variables always being datatype VARCHAR2. I don't know sufficient about SQL Developer to be certain about that ;-)

Comment: SQL Developer doesn't ask so it's probably VARCHAR2